# Smart Lights - colour dilemma

Tags: led, light, bulb

I am trying to select a smart light for my room. But there is a confusion here. I want pure white light. The bulbs that I am showing in the screenshot show in their descriptions that they emit all kind of colours. 
Will there be an effect due to the difference in their Outer colours (white/blue/yellow) on the shades of light emitted? 
Please suggest.

[image]

Comment: Pure white exists in paint (Munsell N10).  Lighting is much more complicated because *light sources* are different.  Do you want sunny-day white (6000K), cloudy-day white (5100K), office white (4000K), halogen white (3000K) or good old fashioned Edison "warm" white (2700K)?  And we're not even getting into CRIs yet.

Comment: You aren't going to get a good idea of the different "whites" from web pages. And, I suspect that a light that can generate full RGB colors isn't going to be very good at a specific, pure white.

Comment: wrt to Harper's comment, I am wanting a Smart light that can be turned to White during day time and orange or yellow during the evening or night time. Like the colours of our screen are whn night mode is enabled in our iPhones. The second bulb in the screenshot for example, has it's outer colour Blue. So I am confused, if the light emitted by it will be affected by the Blue colour on it's outside surface. The same confusion with the third bulb in the screenshot.

Comment: what do you mean by `Outer colours` ?

Comment: The physical color of the bulb. Implying, The Blue color like it is in the middle bulb in this given screenshot. I hope this clears the point.